# Access page variables in base twig template in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

The basic structure of my symfony is as follows.
I have one base template, with head, meta tags, body wrapper bit of jq a.o.
All other elements are loaded inside this template, rendered as blocks for example.

Basicly I have a shop, where the product overview and detail of the products are displayed/rendered in the main template.

So my problem is this. Can I access the variables in this block?
More specific, I want to use the page title in my header.

However when i print all the values in _context I cant find the page title.
I have a page object, but it only contains the title of my site.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you pass this `page object` to twig?

Comment: I'm not sure. I have a few Bundles, but I cant seem to find a controller for my base template.

Comment: You can easily access variable inside a block. I think you are extending that layout right? For example; your template is product.html.twig and that extends layout.html.twig that has blocks like content head meta tags etc.

Comment: You want to access a variable of the block context in another context?

Comment: I tried to access a page variable in the parent context. I think it was an error in my SEO extention.